# pop-up window close with "add to cart" button

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to setup a shopping cart form function (add to cart button) which is called via JavaScript. I have this in a pop-up window and want to have the "add to cart" button both close the pop-up window and also load the info in the main window. Does anyone know what script modifications I need to have?

Here is my current code in the pop-up window to generate the add to cart:

```
<form class="cart" action="index-shop.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-id" value="book 1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-name" value="book 1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-price" value="35.00" />
    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-url" value="http://www.amazoni.com" />
    Qty: <input type="text" name="my-item-qty" value="1" size="3" />
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="my-add-button" value="add to cart" />
</form>
```

Comment: use jquery ui dialog on [here](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: where is the code that executes for you "add to cart" button? if you do not have any then the window is always going to close, this is the default behaviour. 
are you using jquery? if not you should! the rest of the world is.
you want to return false after the code to add the product to the cart has executed

Comment: you'll have to use ajax to post the form and take the action and method out of the form tag

Comment: can this be done via javascript? anyone have any code… not really sure for jquery dialog - as this is being triggered initially from an image map link that pops-up the window with the add to cart button as code above.

Comment: Hi again Gabe, sorry I must've fell asleep, or got really busy at work, I'll post an answer, but only if you're comfortable using jquery. are you ok with that?

Comment: yes, that would be super Pythonian - thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so assuming you've included the jquery file somewhere before this in you webpage, this is how I would go about solving the problem you're having;

```
<form class="cart">
   <input type="hidden" name="my-item-id" value="book 1" />
   <input type="hidden" name="my-item-name" value="book 1" />
   <input type="hidden" name="my-item-price" value="35.00" />
   <input type="hidden" name="my-item-url" value="http://www.amazoni.com" />
   Qty: <input type="text" name="my-item-qty" value="1" size="3" />
   <input class="button" type="submit" id="my-add-button" name="my-add-button" value="add to cart" />
</form>
<script type="type/JavaScript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".cart").submit(function(e){
         e.preventDefault(); //prevent the form from submitting
      });

      //send the form to the server mimicking the post behaviour, without submitting the form
      $("#my-add-button").click(function(){
         $.post("index-shop.php", $(".cart").serialize(), function(data){
            if(data.success){ // this is assuming you created a variable indicating whether server processing succeeded
               /*
               * here we insert the post server processing code
               * and then we close the dialog
               */
            }else{
               alert(data.error); //if there's an error we display the error message and keep the dialog window open allowing the user to continue
            }
         });

         return false;
      });
   });
</script>
```

get back to me if you're having anymore problems or need a little more direction.
I'm South African by the way; and our time is 13:30 right now. . .about to go on my lunch break soon